# Using certain parts of URL as params in a Grails Controller

Tags: grails

I've created a static URL in `Grails`:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        ...

        "/remittance/bank"{
            controller={"BankRemittance"}
            action=[GET:"index"]
        }
        "/remittance/bank/$bankId/spd/$spdId"{
            controller={"SPD"}
            action=[GET:"show"]
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Now what I want is to retrieve `bankId` and `spdId` values of the URL on my `SPDController`:

```
class SPDController {
    def myService

    def show() {
        String bankId = ? // code to get bankId from the URL
        String spdId = ? // code to get spdId from the URL

        render(
            view: "...",
            model: myService.transact(bankId, spdId)
        )
    }
}
```

But how can I do that? It seems using `params.bankId` and `params.spdId` is not for this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action should accept the URL parameters as arguments.

```
def show(String bankId...)
```

Comment: So then, how should my `URLMappings` look like? Is it just that?

Comment: Correct! Specifying the variable in the URL and defining the parameter will cause the method to be invoked with the URL params mapped to their equivalent arguments.